# Migration from Starteam to SVN

Tags: c++, c, svn, starteam, migrating

One of our main project is migrating from Starteam to SVN. The sub-projects within the main project are sharing multiple header and source files. As Starteam supports references it was easy for us to modify a shared header/source file and check it in. Starteam used to take care of updating it in all the sub-projects. Then we used to build all the sub-projects which depend on the shared file. This used to be our regular process of updating shared files in case of Starteam.

As we are migrating to SVN it does not support references and updating any shared file in one of the project does not get updated in all the other project folders. To overcome this problem we have separated shared files and placed them in a common place and modified visual studio settings so that all the projects access the shared file from the same location. Everything went fine with this plan for some sub-projects. But encountered a problem with one of the sub-project. The problem is as follows:

For our example sake i will take 3 sub-projects which share 'a.h', 'b.h', 'a.cpp' and 'b.cpp'. 'a.cpp' includes 'a.h' and 'b.cpp' includes 'b.h'. Project 1 and 2 share all these files so no problem but project 3 shares only 'a.cpp', 'b.h' and 'b.cpp'. 'a.h' is local to project 3. When i include 'b.h' directory in project 3, visual studio is including shared 'a.h' into 'a.cpp' instead of project 3's local file 'a.h'. I have searched in internet for a option in visual studio where in only a single header could be included instead of the entire directory but could not get one.

Requesting you all to provide me a better solution for this migration or some visual studio option to include a single header file instead of the whole directory.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> As we are migrating to SVN it does not support references and updating any shared file in one of the project does not get updated in all the other project folders.

RLLY?! You must to:

- read and grok [SVN externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html) in at least SVNBook and maybe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svn-externals)
- transform all references to externals (file- or directory-type)

and you'll be able use it without any VS-specific tricks, on pure Subversion features